# a query type with the same name already exists

Tags: entity-framework-core

> The entity type 'MyType' cannot be added to the model because a query type with the same name already exists.

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbQuery<MyType> MyTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Exception is thrown here

        //needed b/c table is not named MyTypes
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyType>()
            .ToTable("MyType");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `DbQuery` to `DbSet`.  [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) are used for Views, [among other things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types#usage-scenarios).

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //DbSet not DbQuery
    public DbSet<MyType> MyTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you and I had the same problem on the same day :)

My issue was that I had my view set up as DBset:

```cs
public virtual DbSet<VwVendors> VwVendors{ get; set; }
```

But my mapping was set up as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder.Query<VwVendors>()
    .ToView("vw_Vendors");
```

My fix was to do the opposite of what you did. I had to change DbSet to DbQuery.

Your answer helped me get mine :D

Comment: That's awesome!  That's why I try to share by debugging and results with the community! 